# Sub-population analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, population

I'm facing a statistical issue.

I'm analysing a medical dataset, in which I have a full population. I know if they have a certain disease or not.
Let's say I have 100 000 people on this, 20% having the disease.

Now, I want to know if "Being older than 80" increases the risk of having the disease.
I select all people in my full population that are over 80.
Let's say, in this sub-population, I have 5 000 people, and 30% having the disease.

I'm stuck in this point : Even though the percentage of people having the disease is higher in my sub-population, since I have way less people, I think this could also be linked with incertitude and "uncluck".
Does some metric exists to show if my sub-population rate change is due to incertitude, or is really due to the fact I selected the 80+, and they appear to be risky.

What I tried :

- Applying a confidence interval in my sub-population, and looking if my global population rate is in : The interval is like [29.5, 30.5] and is way far, but seems to be a nonsense, since it gives the possible value of my sub-population rate, and will never be linked with the global population one
- Comparison of 2 proportions : Seems not perfect to me since my 2 populations are not independant, and way unbalances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself found an answer through the book [100 Statistical tests, Kanji (1995)](http://117.3.71.125:8080/dspace/bitstream/DHKTDN/6398/1/100%20statistical%20tests.5792.pdf)

The test to apply in such a situation is "Test 5 Z-test for the equality of two proportions
(binomial distribution)", you can find it at the 27th page of the book ( = 36th slide of the pdf )